# Why do "retry" messages show up on wrong order for other users at chat?

Tags: bug, chat

When I send messages on the chat I usualy get some 'unsent' warnings:

[image: example]

It does happens mainly because of my internet connection quality which is currently low (3g modem). It occurs more often when I have, in a example, an YouTube video and the chat opened at the same time.

When I click at 'retry' to send the message again it works fine on my screen, but for the other users the messages appear out of their order messing up with it's meaning (and I just realize this after rejoin the room).

**Screenshots sequence example:**

**A**- Some messages are sent with success, except one:

[image: moment A]

**B**- I click on retry and the failure message is sent and appears to be fine. This is what I get:

[image: moment B.1]

**C**- This is what the other users get instead (and me after rejoin the room):

[image: Moment B.2]

The other users get the sentences in a different (wrong) order, which can result in misunderstandings.

Comment: The third way is the "correct" way since the third message was sent *after* the fourth. But this probably isn't a good way UX... not that big a deal though (how often do you run into this? :)).

Comment: How often? More than once in a single conversation. Unfortunately this is a big deal for me yes;

Comment: If users have already seen lines 1, 2, 4 won't it be just as confusing for a new line to show up between 2 and 4? When you are dealing with chats like this there is no good way to handle situations where something isn't sent other then to delay everything after it.

Comment: @JoeW your point also "happens" when the messages are edited (and 'edit' is an avaible feature).

Comment: That doesn't mean that is the best way to handle that either.

Answer (score 1):

You are being [rate limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/186281). You are typing short sentences very quickly and sending more than one message a second.

> - 1 second between two messages, here's the true throttle curve
>
> [image: Curve]

---

Slow down. Type complete sentences instead of four short phrases. It's more helpful for others to get your complete thought than it is to get a long stream of quick phrases. If you more fully explain what you are trying to say, it's easier to understand what you need to communicate. As a side benefit, it also slow you down enough to not hit the rate limits.

Comment: Type longer phrases. "test 1" "test 2", etc can easily be sent in sub-one second timeframes. That newest screenshot doesn't change my answer. To me, it shows that you *are* hitting the rate limits.

Comment: I don't think this is a rate limit - it's probably just an internet connection that likes to drop the occasional packet or something similar.

Comment: The bug to which I referred on the question was the sentences order, not the 'send' error. "You are typing short sentences very quickly" - No, you can notice on the [first screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPBhu.png) I got the 'timeout' warning on my very first sentence. Anyway, in my opinion the sentence order is a problem regardless of the user behavior.